# In Android How to receive String from Asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android project, inside the `MainActivity` I have  :

```
String receivedData = new myTask().execute().get();
```

Now `myTask`-task is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView finalResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_it);
        finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String receivedData = new myTask().execute().get();
                finalResult.setText(receivedData);
            }
        });
    }

    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<Myobject> newObject = new ArrayList<Myobject>();
            try {
                //here I add object valus to the list 
                newObject.add(valueadded)
            } catch {
                Exception e
            }
            //here returning the value as String
            return gson.toJson(newObject);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String receivedData = result;
        }
    }
}
```

But **receivedData**  is not receiving any value from `AsyncTask`.
Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should initialize your receivedData inside onPostExecute() method of your asyncTask

Comment: `get()` will freeze UI until result is not return from doInBackground so use `onPostExecute` for showing data in UI which is return from `doInBackground `

Comment: use `onPostExecute` method and return your string there..

Answer (score 1):

Your AsyncTask is defined as this:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
```

The last generic type is the type of your result.  You have Void there.  That means your AsyncTask does not return a value.  If you want a String result, you will have to define it like this:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

This means you can now return a String from doInBackground().

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String receivedData;
    private Button button;
    private TextView finalResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_do_it);
        finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new myTask().execute().get();
            }
        });
    }

    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<Myobject> newObject = new ArrayList<Myobject>();
            try {
                //here I add object valus to the list 
                newObject.add(valueadded)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //here returning the value as String
                return gson.toJson(newObject);
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String receivedData = result;
            finalResult.setText(receivedData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please check the place from where that value is being sent? Are you sure that a value is being sent from server/backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can add onPostExecute method inside the AsynchTask to receive the String. Like Below

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        .........
        return someString;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String receivedData = result;
    }
}
```